# How to get the right coordinates on a QGIS map?

Tags: coordinates, qgis

I am using QGIS and I imported the Google maps sattelite map. Then I drew a line and measured the distance using the Measure Tool, but the distance is inaccurate (it says about 1200 m, but I know it should be 780 m). Also, when I look at the coordinates of a point on the map (shown in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9280t.jpg): coordinates of the point with a star on it), it is different from the coordinates I find when looking up the coordinates online (https://www.gps-coordinates.net/) (shown in Figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHrK8.png): coordinates of the same point as in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9280t.jpg)), so there is probably something wrong there.

I imported the Google maps sattelite map via: browser panel --> XYZ tiles -> Sattelite -> New Connection -> URL = http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}. 
I drew the line in a 'lines layer'.

I already changed the CRS to ETRS89/UTM zone 32N (I am looking at a place in eastern Germany) both in the general project properties and in the layer which includes the line I drew. I also checked whether the unit of distance was right, and it is indeed meters. Lastly, I changed the coordinates from X and Y to degrees/minutes/seconds. Nothing worked and the result stays about 1200 m.

I hope you can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: what  do you mean with  "when I look at the coordinates of a point on the map, it is different from the coordinates I find when looking up the coordinates online"  ??  WE we don't see  your screen  then  .. show a clear data sample of your value  nad the expected  value

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, I am sorry for the confusion. I edited my question and added two screenshots. I hope this makes everything clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out how to fix the problem. It turns out the map I was using did not use the right coordinates (I still don't know why). I now added another map (QuickMapServices) and this one does use the right coordinates. The Measuring Tool also gives the right distance now.